# Best Way to Check if Browser Page is Ready in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, do-loops

I've seen three different ways to check if the page I'm navigating to is ready. As shown in the sample code below.

It seems to me Method 1 is the best, but hoping an expert out there can tell otherwise or even better... provide the right way to do it if there is something different.

Here's the sample code

```
Sub OpenBrowser()
    Dim vOBJBROWSER As Object
    Set vOBJBROWSER = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    vOBJBROWSER.Navigate "http://stackoverflow.com"

    'Method 1
    Do While vOBJBROWSER.Busy Or vOBJBROWSER.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'Method 2
    Do While vOBJBROWSER.ReadyState < 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    'Method 3
    Do
    Loop Until vOBJBROWSER.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    vOBJBROWSER.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd go with Method 1 (source: I used to work on Internet Explorer when I was at Microsoft), but change the `4` to `READYSTATE_COMPLETE`.

Comment: I'd change `Dim vOBJBROWSER As Object` to `Dim browser AS InternetExplorer.Application` and add a project-reference to the WebBrowser COM library.

Comment: Thank you both. Yes. In another example I'm using the internet explorer class. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

The IE browser is going to make you really hate life in the long run.

Just like any browser'ed solution in webs scraping, you only need the browser, if you cant figure out what the resource is you're trying to load.

Consider all the over-head, javascript, CSS, potential tracking cookies, that accompany using a browser.

Now if you know what you want, and see in Chrome Dev Tools how it loads - you can use VBA's HTTP request libraries and you'll have a much better time.

The pro to using a HTTP request is that even it's a stream or chunked, you can control and easily measure when the message is done. A web page you'll always be stuck trying to figure out what the status code is, and sub frames, and all kinds of crap.

Highly recommend, channeling the frustration of IE automation into a learning experience with HTTP and chrome dev tools. You will 100% be less likely to smash your keyboard.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the feedback. In this case a browser is needed because an OAuth2 flow that prompts the user through the browser to allow access. Unless what you suggested gets around that

Comment: @ptownbro OAuth/OIDC supports Device Flow and Client Credential grants for this purpose. The browser-based authentication pop up (hybrid flow) is only meant for web-applications and certain classes of mobile-device apps, not desktop applications.

Comment: Yes. Of course. But the project is an office application. Thanks for your input.